# is there a function for enter string until user enter ('\n')?

Tags: compiler-errors

I can't find a program that enters string from the user until the user enters (enter)

```
# include<iostream>
  int main(){

     string a;
     int cnt=0;
      int i=0;
      while(cin>>a&&a[i]!='\n')
      {
         cnt++;
              }
          cout<< cnt;

         return 0;
      }
```

it appears to me that it's an infinite loop

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do, but reading input into a `string` until new line sounds like [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).